# How to know if a Linux command can read from STDIN?

Tags: command-line, pipe

I noticed this problem when I became confused with pipe, one command send its executing output to the `STDOUT`, which is the `STDIN` for the other command, which can read from `STDIN`.

How do I know if a Linux command can read from `STDIN`?

Is there a feature to distinguish commands that can read from `STDIN` from those cannot?

Comment: I think this is a per-application thing. The best way to know is really just to read the man page or test it yourself.

Comment: This would require solving the halting problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(In response to the upvotes on my comment)*

There isn't a concrete way of determining if an application reads from `STDIN` or something else. In general, you'll have to try piping something to it or reading the program's `man` page.